# SQL Server: Substring based on first two characters being a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a text field and want to pull out an ID number from the field - the ID always starts with an 8 and is 12 characters long (e.g 899900014658), the current code uses the substring method below:

```
substring(textfield,charindex('8',textfield),12) as extractedID
```

This pulls out anything starting with an 8 though so I'm getting results like '8 am', '8 February' etc in the extractedID field.

Is there a method of extracting anything starting with an 8 where the second and third characters are also a number?

edit - solved using PATINDEX

```
 SUBSTRING(SubmissionDiaryEntry,(PATINDEX('%8[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',SubmissionDiaryEntry)),12)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question:

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Where textfield like '8[0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, it was trying to extract the ID as a new field, have solved using PATINDEX and like method you have suggested above. Thanks

Comment: @GullitsMullet No worries.  Pleased you got to right answer  :)

Answer (score 1):

Ckeck below, it may help:

```
declare @textfield nvarchar(20) = '845456798234'

select case when substring(@textfield, 2, 1) like '[0-9]' 
                and substring(@textfield, 3, 1) like '[0-9]'  
            then substring(@textfield,charindex('8',@textfield),12) 
        else 'not valid'
        end 
        as extractedID

-- test
set @textfield = '8r5456798234'

select case when substring(@textfield, 2, 1) like '[0-9]' 
                and substring(@textfield, 3, 1) like '[0-9]'  
            then substring(@textfield,charindex('8',@textfield),12) 
        else 'not valid'
        end 
        as extractedID
```

however John's answer is much simplier and it looks like exactly what you are looking for. 
Below is just to clarify..., using John's script, answer to your issue would be:

```
select substring(textfield,charindex('8',textfield),12) as extractedID
from yourTable
where textfield like '8[0-9][0-9]%'
```